# Friendly url apache 2.4.18

Tags: php, linux, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have installed apache 2.4.18 on my linux mint 18.1 "Serena" ciannon. When I log in to the system it gets the page blank and does not load the contents.

- I already activated mod_rewrite
- I've already changed AllowOverride in both apache2.conf and sites-available / 000-default.conf

  ```
  <Directory /var/www/html>
      Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
      AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
      AllowOverride None
      Require all granted
  </Directory>
  ```
- The system works perfectly in my web hosting(Hostagor)
- Every new change I give restart in Apache to be able to validate the changes ...
- On the web server and on the local server the login page loads perfectly and creates the link: system / index.php / auth / login. When I log in, the web server (hostgator) loads the address: mysite.com/system/index.php/ and the system runs, however on the local server it loads the localhost / system / url and does not show the content.

  - I decided to do a test by taking the complete url to register a new patient in the system, www.mysite.com.br / system / patient / new and put it on the local server and gave the same thing, the page goes blank ... meanwhile it only Works and loads the content if I add index.php: system / index.php / patient / new

I do not know what to do anymore ...

Can this be a problem in the friendly url?

Can someone help me?

My htaccess:

```
    RewriteEngine on  
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|uploads|assets|robots\.txt)     
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /system/index.php/$1 [L]   
    DirectoryIndex index.php
```

Ps.Sorry for my english :)

Comment: You have "AllowOverride None" , it is for which directives declared in .htaccess can override earlier configuration directives. Can you change it to "AllowOverride All"

Comment: I changed now, but it didn't work :(